# Multiple layers of quotes in script in PHP variable that is echoed

Tags: php, variables

PHP:

```
$var123 = '<div class="mydiv" onclick="document.getElementById("dialog").style.display = "block";">Some text</div>';
echo($var123);
```

I know this is a total newbie question, but how do I make this work? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use single quotes in Javascript. Since your string is enclosed in single quotes you also need to escape them in PHP with a backslash `\`.

```
$var123 = '<div class="mydiv" onclick="document.getElementById(\'dialog\').style.display = \'block\';">Some text</div>';
echo $var123;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$var123 = 'Some text';
<div class="mydiv" onclick="document.getElementById("dialog").style.display = "block";">
<?php echo $var123; ?>
</div>;
```

Try this